# Guide for esriRasterOpCode

Tags: arcobjects, arcmap, raster

I'm building dynamic cartographic symbols to display inside ArcMap, but they are displaying "wrong".

Is there a guide somewhere that will show what [raster op code](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/esriRasterOpCode_Constants/001w00000034000000/) does? I mean, not only show, but perhaps demonstrate the symbology. The esri pages has confusing descriptions like "it's the inverse of rasterOpCodeXOR" for example.

I've always struggled with this. Any change there are good resources on this?

Comment: Esri's constants correspond to GDI raster operation codes.  Did you try Googling for `GDI raster operation tutorial`?